# C++ project with ascii values

Tags: c++, ascii

I am relatively new to C++ and I was assigned a lab in class that is pretty confusing. I was given this line in a .txt file and I am supposed to read it in and output it into a console:

`63f7hj-9 22spaces L Is this correct`

The first segment is an ASCII value for `?`, I am supposed to set the field width of my output to 22 spaces, aligned left and it will say, Is this correct.

`???????Is this correct`

Above is what the output is supposed to look like. I was successfully able to read in the ASCII value and print 7 `?`s, but I can't figure out how to read in anything else.

This is my code:

```
ifstream inFile;
string word;
int ascii_value;
char ascii_character, word1;

//opens the file
inFile.open("proj1data.txt");


//extracts data from the file

inFile >> ascii_value, word1;
ascii_character=char(ascii_value);


//outputs data to the screen
cout << right;
cout << setfill(ascii_character);
cout << setw(7); 
cout << word1;
```

I hope someone is able to help. Thank you!

Comment: How does `63f7hj-9` correspond to the ASCII value 0x2f or decimal 47?

Comment: You need to look up the `comma operator`.  Your input statement does not do what you think it does.

Comment: BTW, ASCII values are in the range 0..127.  Search the internet for "ASCII table" or `ASCII chart`.  An `int` type can be negative, but ASCII values are not negative.